# What is the correct way to comment out a PHP variable being echoed using shorthand notation?

Tags: php, tags, comments

I have recently started using the PHP shorthand `<?= ?>` tags to echo variables etc in my PHP scripts. However I find if I want to then comment out the variable, e.g. `<?= //$myVariable; ?>` i get a syntax error.

Is it safe to just do this: `<?//= $myVariable; ?>`

Many Thanks!

Comment: [Refer this post might be useful](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php)

Comment: Hey Ranijth, thanks for the link above, i have come across that post separately while deciding to start using the shorthand echo statement.
Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short tag

```
<?= ... ?>
```

is translated into

```
<?php echo ...; ?>
```

So to comment it out, you have to put something into `...` that always shows up as empty. Here's the shortest I can come up with:

```
<?= false && ... ?>
```

This works because `echo false` echoes nothing.

There's no documentation supporting it, so it might be an old compatibility hack, but the following seem to work:

```
<?//= ... ?>
```

and

```
<?/*= ... */?>
```

Since they're undocumented, I wouldn't depend on them for anything important, but you could use them if you're just temporarily commenting something out while debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so what are your thoughts on using `<?//= $myVariable; ?>`
Are those short hand php tags safe in this instance? Or would depend on the specific php.ini setup and should thus be avoided?

Comment: I don't see any mention of that syntax in the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php

Comment: @Barmar, I tested the comment shortcut in PhpStorm. `CTRL /` and I noticed that's what it did. But was unsure if that was a good idea.

Comment: And `CTRL ?` adds `/* ... */` in the short tag. Both seem to work, but they're not supported by any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

So on the question of why `<?/*=...*/?>` and `<?//=...?>` work is because there's a PHP feature called [short_open_tag](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag), that lets you skip putting `php` after `<?` and just go with something like `<? echo ...; ?>`.  It can be disabled in the INI file, and before v5.4 the  short hand wouldn't work unless it was enabled.  So as long as you're in control of your INI file you should be OK.

BUT, I just checked our 5.6.31 system (it's old yes), but when the short_open_tag is set to false the `<? ... ?>` get emitted directly to the client as if it were HTML text.  So, it may be that you just aren't seeing the text because the browser isn't rendering it.